# Problems using pd.cut() with map_partitions DASK

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I´m having trouble aplying the pd.cut with the map_partitions function in dask to a big DataFrame. Using the same bins and labels in pandas, results me with a new column with the labels values.

```
_dict = {'doc_faturamento': ['546102424238'], 'atraso': [0]}

_df = pd.DataFrame( data=_dict)

_df['periodo_atraso'] = pd.cut(x=_df['atraso'], bins=[-10,1, 7, 14, 21, 30, 45,60, 9999999999], labels=['PA/PD','1-7 días', '8-14 días', '15-21 dias', '22-30 dias', '31-45 dias', '46-60 dias', '+ de 60 dias'])
```

But in Dask aplying the following code to a dask dataframe, results with the new column with the bins values.

```
_dict = {'doc_faturamento': ['546102424238'], 'atraso': [0]}

_df = pd.DataFrame( data=_dict)

_df = dd.from_pandas(_df, npartitions=1)

_bins = [-10,0,1, 7, 14, 21, 30, 45,60, 9999999999]
_labels = ['PA/PD','1-7 días', '8-14 días', '15-21 dias', '22-30 dias', '31-45 dias', '46-60 dias', '+ de 60 dias']

_df['periodo_atraso'] = _df['atraso'].map_partitions(pd.cut,_bins,labels=_labels,meta=(None,int))
```

Could anyone help to define parameters?

Comment: It looks like you have an extra element in the `_bins` list when moving to dask.  I found no issue when removing the `0` from `_bins`

Comment: thanks that also was mistaken!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it usually better to use map_partitions as close to the pandas process as possible. In this case, that means instead of creating the series and assigning it,  map to the new version of the dataframe:

```
def mapper(df):
    df['periodo_atraso'] = pd.cut(x=_df['atraso'], 
        bins=[-10,1, 7, 14, 21, 30, 45,60, 9999999999], 
        labels=['PA/PD','1-7 días', '8-14 días', '15-21 dias', '22-30 dias', '31-45 dias', '46-60 dias', '+ de 60 dias'])
    return df

new_df = df.map_partitions(mapper)
```

For the `meta` parameter, you can feed a small amount of the data in as a pandas dataframe, e.g.,

```
df_small = pd.DataFrame(data=_dict)
meta = mapper(df_small).iloc[:0]
```